# Does every sequence of digits occur in one of the primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exact-sequence

I was triggered by the discussion "does every arbitrary digit sequence of length N occur in the decimals of Pi"

Although Pi is irrational and contains an infinite number of decimals, it seems that every sequence of N digits does not necessarily occur in Pi's decimals.

But I have another question, and I did not find any discussion about it. *Does every sequence of N digits occur in at least one of the prime numbers*.

So I am not asking if a certain prime number contains every possible sequence of N digits. To me it seems obvious that there does not exist such a prime number.

When N is small, it is obvious that every sequence will occur in at least one prime number. But when N gets larger, the prime numbers containing this sequence will become less.

Is there a largest N, where the sequence will not occur anymore in a prime number? Since the number of primes is infinite, so there will exist a prime number with an infinite number of digits (is that true?). So it is likely that every digit sequence will occur in at least one prime number. Is this something which can be proven?

Comment: Do you have any proof that "every number sequence of N numbers does not necessarily occur in Pi's decimals"?

Comment: @Mohammad One does not have to prove that something is not known to be true. At least, not mathematically. If you are aware of a result that says the converse, then this would be interesting indeed!

Comment: (what I mean is: he says "does not necessarily occur", not "there are sequences that do not occur")

Comment: @57Jimmy I think you misunderstood my opinion. If it is not known that $\pi$ is normal, there is no point in just 'assuming' that it is not. No converse has been found so far. Assumptions should be based on some observation.

Comment: @Hans I find your question very interesting, but one of your last sentences is definitely wrong: any prime number has only finitely many digits!

Comment: @Mohammad Sure, I agree. But the new question is still legitimate. Since we can't prove or disprove the first (so far), we can try to ask another one

Comment: Every finite sequence of digits occurs in infinitely many primes. That is a consequence of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, and in a different way of the prime number theorem. (Dirichlet's theorem shows the sequence occurs infinitely often near the end of the prime's decimal [or other base] representation, the PNT shows it occurs infinitely often near the front.) Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @57Jimmy duly noted.

Comment: @57jimmy. I think you are right that there are infinitely many prime numbers, but every prime number has a finite number of digits. One of the pitfalls of the definition of infinite and I stepped into it! What hold is, I think,  there will always be a prime number with a larger number of digits than a given number of digits.

Comment: @Hans Exactly, that's the point

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. That is what I asked and your answer is even stronger. I asked if the is at least one prime which contains a finite sequence of digits. You state that every finite number occurs in an infinite number of primes, not just (at least) one. Only the explanation that is occurs near the end of the prime's decimals (Dirichlet) or near the front (PNT) I don't understand.

Comment: Let $n$ be the number whose decimal expansion is the given sequence [allowing possible leading zeros]. If $n$ is even or divisible by $5$, then a prime cannot end with that sequence (except for the trivial cases that the sequence is "2" or "5"). In that case, let $m=10\cdot n+1$, otherwise let $m = n$. So the decimal expansion of $m$ has at most $N+1$ digits, and $m$ is coprime to $10$. By Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a\cdot 10^{N+1} + m$, and the given digit sequence makes up either the last $N$ digits of such a prime, or the $N$ digits before the last.

Comment: Thus the sequence appears "near the end" of such a prime. For the argument with the prime number theorem, we let $m = n$ if the sequence doesn't begin with a zero, and $m = 10^N + n$ if the sequence begins with a zero. By the prime number theorem, for all large enough $k$ there is a prime between $m\cdot 10^k$ and $(m+1)\cdot 10^k$. The decimal expansion of such primes either starts with the given sequence (if the sequence doesn't begin with $0$) or has the given sequence as its second to $N+1^{\text{st}}$ digit, so "near the front".

Comment: I was triggered by the discussion "does every arbitrary number sequence of length N occur in the decimals of Pi"? My conjecture to this would be yes, unless, of course there is already a proof.

Comment: @HansLinkels If you mean : "Does every finite sequence of digits (and therefore every natural number) occur in any prime" then "number seqeuence" is a misleading and unfortune formulation. You could as well mean : "Does the sequence of the squares (for example) occur in any prime" (which is of course not the case).

Comment: @J.Linne It is an open problem whether $\pi$ contains every finite digit string, but it is widely believed because the many many calculated digits behave like a random sequence. My personal intuition is that it is not the case, but a proof of this will almost certain be out of reach, whereas the proof that $\pi$ contains every finite digit-sequence is much more imaginable.

Comment: @J.Linne We even do not know from a single digit whether it occurs infinite many often in the decimal expansion of $\pi$, we cannot even rule out that the decimal expansion eventually only contains of (for example) ones and zeros. This is the reason of my doubt.

Comment: @HansLinkels A given prime number can of course not contain every finite digit-sequence because it only has finite many digits. But as mentioned by Daniel Fischer, for every finite digit sequence, there are infinite many primes containing it.

Comment: @Peter: I intended to say "every sequence of digits". The unfortunate exprssion "sequence of numbers" is a result of me being a non-native English speaker. As an example, the sequence 4748 does not occur in 2305843009213693951 but it does occurs in 2147483647. So the statement holds that 4748 occurs in at least one prime number. Now, if I take such a sequence of digits, of length N, will there always be a prime numbers containing that sequence?

Comment: @everyone, including moderators:stupid and obvious typos and spelling errors in my comment are a result of the rule that it is only allowed to edit a comment for 5 minutes. Not because I am too stupid to spot them or too lazy to correct them.

Comment: I have edited the title and the contents. Now I am describing "sequence of digits", which is I think the correct expression. Thanks @Peter for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem (Dirichlet): If $a,b\in \Bbb N$ with $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then the set $S(a,b)=\{na+b: n\in \Bbb N\}$ contains infinitely many primes.

For a sequence $(b_j)_{1\leq j\leq m}$ of decimal digits (with $m\in \Bbb N$) let $b=1+\sum_{j=1}^m b_j10^{m+1-j}$ and let $a=10^{m+1}.$ Then $S(a,b)$ contains infinitely many primes, and  the sequence of decimal digits of every member of $S(a,b)$ contains the consecutive sub-sequence $(b_j)_{1\leq j\leq m}.$

For the purposes of this Q it is sufficient that $S(a,b)$ contains at least one prime, but it is easily  shown that this is equivalent to  Dirichlet's theorem, which is not easy to prove. It was one of the first (or the first) results in Number Theory whose proof used methods from Analysis.